# Selecting the SUM of a group as well as values of that groups largest ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table below:

| id | locid | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 631 | 337 | 0 |
| 2 | 123 | 102 | 235 | 0 |
| 3 | 123 | 99 | 7 | 0 |
| 4 | 456 | 471 | 74 | 0 |
| 5 | 456 | 65 | 532 | 0 |
| 6 | 456 | 21 | 17 | 0 |

The goal is to get the following result:

| locid | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 832 | 7 | 0 |
| 456 | 557 | 17 | 0 |

Essentially, I'm grouping the results based on 'locid' and getting the sum of column 'val1' for each group. However, I'd also like to get columns 'val2' and 'val3' for the largest 'id' in each group.

I seem to be able to get each result as separate queries, but when I try to put them together I'm unable to get the result I want. My current SQL is as follows (which is returning all values correctly except the sum of 'val1':

```
SELECT a.locid, sum(a.val1), val2, val3 
FROM table a 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT locid, MAX(id) id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY locid
) b ON a.locid = b.locid AND a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.locid
```

Comment: where does the id in your result come from?

Comment: Whoops! That was a mistake, I've removed the id column. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?  and what data type is id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't have window function.and use a mysql 5.x version

```
SELECT 
 `locid`
, SUM(val1)
, (SELECT val2 FROM table1 WHERE id = MAX(t1.`id`)) val2
, (SELECT val3 FROm table1 WHERE id = MAX(t1.`id`)) val3
FROM table1 t1
GROUP By  `locid`
```

Comment: The id column was a mistake, it shouldn't have been in the expected result table.

Comment: Yup, this did the trick. I guess I just needed to have sub-queries in the SELECT statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions with `select distinct`:

```
select distinct locid, sum(val1) over (partition by locid),
       first_value(val2) over (partition by locid order by id) as val2,
       first_value(val3) over (partition by locid order by id) as val3
from t;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have an aggregation function for "first()"/"last()".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54ba3af0286c7bf48ae0212b6b2fc8e7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @ysth . . . Did you try it?  I added a db<>fiddle illustrating that it works.

Comment: sorry, missed the distinct.